# I want to hook up two lights and two separate switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I want to hook up two lights and two switches. There are three cables. One has three black wires, the other two have one yellow wire and one black wire each. I'm assuming that one of the cables with one yellow wire and one black wire goes to one light and the other goes to the other light and the cable with three black wires is the power coming from the breaker box. The lights were already installed but they both ran to one switch and I want them to have their own individual switches. Where do I go from this point?[image][image][image]

Comment: The colors sound a bit unusual. What country are you in? Can you post pictures of the wires and existing switch?

Comment: Im in spokane wa. Usa. I thought the colors seemed odd also, but then i reminded myself that the house was built in 1960, so thats what i attributed it to. They did things a lot different back then than they do now a days... Ill try to get some pictures up, soon! I know they make all the difference in the world...

Comment: I suspect the "yellow" is really white that changed over the last 58 years. But that doesn't explain the cable with 3 blacks. In an older house (like mine too), you may not have ground wires everywhere. But you should still have "white = neutral" and "non-white, typically black = hot".

Comment: Can you post a clear photo looking into the back of the existing switch box? You may have conduits instead of cables....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I'll try just as soon as i get home, which should be within a couple of hours. Is there a difference between cables & conduits? And if so, can you explain it to me? Please & Thank-you. 

Comment: @PaulaMaryVinson -- we'll know more once we see the photo

Comment: Is it an off-white color like a beige found on a wall? Or is it a "That color belongs on a Ferrari" bright organic banana yellow?

Comment: A cable is a group of wires, in this context typically between two and four insulated wires plus a bare ground wire, all together inside a plastic (or in old days, rubber or cloth) sleeve. Each wire in a cable is typically a different color - e.g., black, white, red. A popular brand of cable is Romex. A conduit is a metal or plastic tube that you can run individual wires through. Because you can run whatever wires you want, the rules are a little different as far as the colors. Cables are often much cheaper & easier to run, but conduit provides more flexibility for many situations.

Comment: The single black wire with orange wire nut, was attached to the bottom screw on the switch. The 3 black wires with a wire nut (top right, in the photo.) was attached to the top screw on the switch. And a single black & 2 yellow wires (bottom right, in photo.) just had a wire nut on them. Also, to answer your question Harper, the 2 yellow wires are more off white then banana yellow. Sorry it took so long to post the photos guys, it took me a few to figure out how to add them! But once i figured it out, it was a breeze! Hope they help YOU to help ME. Thanx everyone, its very greatly appreciated!

Comment: @manassehkatz, Thank you for responding. Now i can positively say they are cables & NOT conduit.

Comment: So the yellow is what I earlier suspected was *really white that changed over the last 58 years*. The 3 blacks together are probably hot coming in, hot going to switch, hot going to someplace else. The single black would be your switched-hot. And the rest...I'm not sure but Harper should be able to figure it out.

Comment: When the power it turned off to this switch are any outlets also dead ? To me it sounds like the hotts are combined and going to the switch and another location, if this is the case the 1 wire going to the lights would require pulling a 2nd wire to be able to controll both lights separately.

Comment: Yes. The two outlets in that room, the porch light and the livingroom outlets upstairs. That room is downstairs in the basement.

Comment: Is re-running the cable from the switch to the lights an option?

Comment: No, not really. It would require a lot of tearing down and then rebuilding, which i can not afford for sure! I honestly didnt think that it would be too much of a problem for me to add another light switch so i could use the lights separately. (its just too much lighting for that area when they both go on...) Boy, was i ever wrong!! So in order to have two switches, i would need another black wire?

Comment: Couldnt i just attach two short pieces of wire with a wirenut to each of the switches?

Comment: What is above the room in question?

Comment: The kitchen and upstairs hallway

Comment: What if I just hook it back up like it was with only one switch but add two short pieces on each of the two switches I'm wanting to hook up? Would that work???